# Dompdf generatin PDF with red lines

Tags: php, css, pdf, dompdf

I'm trying to generate a pdf file and red lines appear throughout the pdf. I followed the directions found online:

```
    $html_content = "<p>Testing123</p>";
    $html_content = trim(stripslashes($html_content));
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($html_content);
    $dompdf->set_paper('letter', 'portrait');
    $dompdf->render();

    //echo "end!";exit(0);

    $dompdf->stream("newfile.pdf");
    exit(0);
```

What am i doing wrong, is there an instruction I overlooked. I also dont think its my css.

```
<style type="text/css">
        @page{ margin: 2cm;}
      body{ font-family: sans-serif; margin: 0.5cm 0; text-align: left;  }
      #header,#footer{ position: fixed; left: 0; right: 0; color: #aaa; font-size: 0.4em; }
      #header{top: 0;border-bottom: 0.1pt solid #aaa;}
      #footer{bottom: 0;border-top: 0.1pt solid #aaa;}
      #header table,#footer table {width: 100%;border-collapse: collapse;}
      #header td,#footer td{padding: 0;width: 50%;}
      .page-number{text-align: center;}
      .page-number:before{content: "Page " counter(page);}
      hr{page-break-after: always;border: 0;}
      table{border-collapse: separate;border: none;}
      td{font-size: 11px;text-align: left;vertical-align: bottom;border-width: 1px;border-color:  #333;line-height: 5px;}
      td label{font-weight: normal;font-size: 12px;line-height: 14px;color: #333}
      td p{font-weight: normal;font-size: 11px;line-height: 11px;margin: 5px 0;color: #333;}
      .written_field{ border-bottom: 1px solid black;}
     </style>
```

Result:
[image]

Would appreciate any assistance in this issue. If its unclear please let me know and I'll try to be more detailed.

Comment: What does the content of your **$html_content** look like ?

Comment: Looks like you have layout debugging enabled. Ensure that the `DEBUG_LAYOUT` configuration constant is set to false. You can set it from dompdf_config.inc.php or dompdf_custom_config.inc.php

Comment: Thanks BrianS, your solution worked splendidly but I also found another issue. When i have multiple columns in one row, the last column has no right border. I read somewhere that it might be because i am using percentage but with pt and px, i still get the same result. Any solution for that one?

Comment: related to previous comment: I am able to use 50% colspan but when using 33%, i had no luck with getting the border for the last column.

Comment: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/904

Comment: Please don't use comments to ask a new question. Instead add an answer or remove your original question, so that people don't feel compelled to answer your question even though it has been solved already by someone else, and then create a new question.